# Avoid jQuery UI resizable 'alsoResize' to move in opposite direction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gRJGoQjKThiAVBgDnK5f?p=preview) I have two divs, the orange div is resizable and has the option `alsoResize` to resize the blue div.

If you resize by dragging the right or bottom sides of the orange div, it works well. However, if you resize the top or left sides, the blue div is resized in the opposite direction. How to make the blue div resize in the same direction as the orange div?

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" 
style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:orange;margin:30px;float:left"></div>

<div id="div2" 
style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue;margin:30px;float:left"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#div1').resizable({
      handles: 'all',
      alsoResize: '#div2'
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alsoResize` option only updates the width and height of the corresponding elements, however resizing from the north or west sides uses `top` and `left`, which `alsoResize` doesn't consider.

You can implement your own `resize` handler which you can use to copy the `top` and `left` difference across elements:

```
$('#div1').resizable({
    handles: 'all',
    alsoResize: '#div2',
    start: function() {
        this.div2pos = $("#div2").offset();
    },
    resize: function(e, ui) {
        var left = ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left;
        var top = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top;
        var pos = this.div2pos;
        $("#div2").offset({top: pos.top + top, left: pos.left + left});
    }
});
```

Beware, though: `resize` handlers are called continuously while dragging, and `.offset` is a rather heavy function. If the rest of your page is also heavy (or even if just the user's browser is slow), this can result in a choppy animation. You can improve this by switching to using `.css({top:.. left:..})` but the exact implementation would depend on your actual use case.