# resizing a div with jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I m currently using jquery-ui for resizing a div. What i m trying to do is when i resize the outside div, also inside div should be resized as well. For example if the outside div's height got 50px bigger than inside div should be 50px bigger as well. Is there anyway to do it with only css ?

```
<div id="window-x" class="ui-widget-content" style="height: 100px; width:50px; border: solid">
 <div id="smallFrame"style="height: 50px; width:25px; border: solid"></div>
</div>
$( "#window-x" ).resizable({
         minHeight: $( "#smallFrame").height(),
         minWidth:$( "#smallFrame").width(),  
        },
                {
  resize: function( event, ui ) {
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/8575/

Comment: You could just set it to `50%`: http://jsfiddle.net/w9eox5ar/, or if it's not %-based use [`alsoResize`](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-alsoResize). If you want more fine-grained control, I recall answering a similar question recently about resizing two boxes simultaniously, you can probably adapt the same method to your requirements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837575/avoid-jquery-ui-resizable-alsoresize-to-move-in-opposite-direction

Answer (score 0):

Set inner div size in percentage.

```
  <div id="smallFrame"style="height: 50%; width:50%; border: solid"></div>


 $( "#window-x" ).resizable({
         minHeight: $( "#smallFrame").height(),
         minWidth:$( "#smallFrame").width(),  
        });
```